# Function to generate specified number of random hex and rgb colors

Tags: javascript, function, generator

Trying to write a function that generates a specified amount of random rgb or hex colors. It takes 'rgb' or 'hex'(type) and then 'n'(quantity to generate) as parameters, but I'm getting NaN when running code. Here's what I have written:

```
function generateColors(type, n) {
    let result = ''
    var quantity = Number(n)
    if (type === 'rgb') {
        let num = Math.round(0xffffff * 
Math.random());
        let r = num >> 16
        let g = num >> 8 & 255
        let b = num & 255
    return ('rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')') * quantity;
  } else if (type === 'hexa') {
        let hexDigits = '0123456789ABCDEF'
        let randomHex= []
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            randomHex += 
hexDigits.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 
hexDigits.length));
    }
    return [randomHex] * quantity; 
  } else {
      console.log('type not applicable')
  }
  return result
}  
console.log(generateColors('rgb', 3))
console.log(generateColors('hexa', 3))
```

Not sure what I'm missing, or if I should do a switch statement instead, but any advice is welcome.

Comment: You are multiplying a string or array by a number. That doesn't repeat the string (like in Python), it tries to convert it to a number. If you expected to generate a longer string, use [`.repeat(quantity)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) instead

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use loop...

you can loop n times inside the function. push the output into the result and return the result. it will look like something like this:

```
function generateColors(type, n) {
  let result = [];
  for (let x = 0; x < n; x++) {
    if (type === "rgb") {
      let num = Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random());
      let r = num >> 16;
      let g = (num >> 8) & 255;
      let b = num & 255;
      result.push("rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")");
    } else if (type === "hexa") {
      let hexDigits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
      let randomHex = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        randomHex += hexDigits.charAt(
          Math.floor(Math.random() * hexDigits.length)
        );
      }
      result.push(randomHex);
    } else {
      console.log("type not applicable");
    }
  }
  return result;
}
console.log("rgb", generateColors("rgb", 3));
console.log("hex", generateColors("hexa", 3));
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-hofstadter-8fl47f?file=/src/index.js) - dont forget to open the console ;)

Answer (score 0):

Or, slightly shorter:

```js
function mulcol(n,hex){
 function rndcol(hex){
  let col=[1,2,3].map(v=>Math.floor(Math.random()*256).toString(hex?16:10).padStart(hex?2:1,"0"));
  return hex?`#${col.join("")}`:`rgb(${col.join(",")})`;
 }
 return [...Array(n)].map(v=>rndcol(hex));
}
 
console.log(mulcol(3)); // RGB output
console.log(mulcol(5,1));// hex output
```

Comment: OP has this part already working. Their problem is the `quantity` handling

Comment: Ok, if the focus should be more on outputting _multiple_ colours then check my answer again ...

Answer (score 0):

```js
const generateColors = (type, num) => {
    let hexChars = '0123456789abcdef'
    colors = []
    if(type=='rgb') {
        for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            let newArr = []
            for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                let rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*256)
                newArr.push(rand)
            }
            let tostring = newArr.join(',')
            finalVal = `rgb(${tostring})`
            colors[i] = finalVal            
        }       
    } else if(type=='hex') {
        for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            colors[i] = '#'
            for (let k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
                let a = Math.floor(Math.random()*hexChars.length) 
                colors[i] += hexChars[a]         
            }
        }
    }
    return colors      
}
console.log(generateColors('rgb',4))
console.log(generateColors('hex',4))
```

The generateColors function takes two parameters, type and num. If the type is 'rgb', it generates random RGB colors by creating num number of them and stores them in an array.

The hexChars variable contains the hexadecimal characters used for RGB colors, and an empty array colors is defined to store the generated colors.

Using nested loops, the function generates num random RGB colors. Each color is represented as an array of three values (e.g., [r, g, b]), where the color values (r, g, b) are randomly selected between 0 and 255.

The generated r, g, and b values are added to a temporary array called newArr.

The newArr array is concatenated using the join() method, and the resulting string is stored in a variable named tostring.

Finally, using this tostring value, the finalVal variable is created and formatted to be in the "rgb(r, g, b)" format.

The colors array is filled with finalVal values, which represent the generated colors, and this array is returned.

If the type is 'hex', the function generates random hex colors. It also generates num random hex colors and stores them in the colors array.

The colors array is defined to store the generated colors, and the hexChars variable contains the hexadecimal characters used for hex colors.

Each color starts with the '#' symbol and consists of six hexadecimal characters. The color value is created using randomly selected characters from hexChars and is added to the colors array.

The generated colors are added to the colors array, which is returned at the end.

The output of the code will be either a set of randomly generated RGB colors in the "rgb(r, g, b)" format or a set of randomly generated hex colors in the "#abcdef" format, depending on the specified type.

Comment: You should add explanation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).